# my react app is getting crashed when i tested it with wrong inputs for api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, user-interface, crash

I guess ! I have hardcoded the response and tried to map the output.But i can't find the other way. even i want to add the fallback ui for wrong inputs. thanks.

.............code......................

```
`
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);
  // const[tit,setTit]=useState("")

  const changeText = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=king&apikey=4efa7c6`)
      .then((response) => {
        setMovie(response.data.Search);
      });
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {

  //      axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${text}&apikey=4efa7c6`)
  //       .then((response)=>{
  //         console.log(response);
  //         setTit(response.data.Search)
  //       });
  //    }, [text]);

  const getMovie = (e) => {
    if (text.length === 0) {
      alert("Please Enter Movie Name..!");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      axios
        .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${text}&apikey=4efa7c6`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          // setMovie(response.data)
          setMovie(response.data.Search);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark ">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a
            className="navbar-brand"
            href="#"
            style={{ color: "crimson", fontWeight: "bolder" }}
          >
            Mflix
          </a>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon bg-light"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <form className="d-flex" role="search" onSubmit={getMovie}>
              <input
                className="form-control me-3 "
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                aria-label="Search"
                value={text}
                onChange={changeText}
              />
              <button className="btn btn-outline-success " type="submit">
                Search
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div className="container my-3">
        <div className="row ">
          {movie.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md my-3 " key={index}>
                <div
                  className="card col-3 mx-auto"
                  style={{ width: "14rem" }}
                  id="res"
                >
                  <img
                    src={value.Poster}
                    className="card-img-top"
                    alt="..."
                    onError={(e) =>
                      (e.target.src =
                        "https://feb.kuleuven.be/drc/LEER/visiting-scholars-1/image-not-available.jpg/image")
                    }
                  />
                  <div className="card-img-overlay">
                    <h5 className="card-title1" id="type">
                      {value.Year}
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-body bg-secondary">
                    <p className="card-text" style={{ fontWeight: "bolder" }}>
                      {value.Title}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}`
```

[response for correct input with Search[response for wrong input without[see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v5Wt.png)  Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e8SO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye8SY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use movie?.map, because you cannot map over undefined

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response.data.Search is returning something undefined or non-array so in your template, movie.map is failing. You could just test movie first by saying movie?.map with the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or you could do something like `{movie && typeof movie === 'object' ? movie.map ... : // show something else here...}` which is just a simple inline [ternary operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Although checking for it being of type object, it could actually be an object and not an array so be careful for that. Probably would want to check the response before you set the movie state

Comment: Thanks it solved my app crashing problem.

Comment: Can you upvote and/or mark my answer as the solution so i can get some reputation points on stack overflow please. Trying to get to that minimum 50 points or whatever. @thotaritikesh